# Range Space and Null Space of Function Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$ D $ and $ A $ are given as the following on an interval $ I $ on $ [a,b] $ :

$ D: C^{k+1}(I) \rightarrow C^k(I), Df(x) = f'(x) $ as the operation of differentiation, and

$A:C^k(I)\rightarrow C^{k+1}(I), Af(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(y)dy$. Compute $DI$ and $ID$.

I used a function space below and compute the linear transformations as such:

$DA$:

$[1, x, x^2] \rightarrow [0,1, 2x] \rightarrow [1 + a, x + a, x^2 + a]$

$AD$:

$[1, x, x^2] \rightarrow [x + a, \frac{1}{2}x^2 +a, \frac{1}{3}x^3 + a] \rightarrow [1, x, x^2]$

To find the null space, I set $f'(x)=0$ and $\int_{a}^{x} f(y)dy=0$.

I am just confused after this step, and how to find the range space/column vector for these functions. Am I approaching this right by using a function space?

Comment: Are you using $I$ for two different purposes?

Comment: You probably mean $DA$ and $AD$.

Comment: Yep, I did, just edited and fixed it!

Comment: Functions act on the left, so it should be $AD$ and $DA$ for the composition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are calculating $AD$ and $DA$ on the space of polynomials of degree $\le 2$ when the domains are $C^{k}(I)$ and $C^{k+1}(I)$. And, you're doing it in the wrong order: $AD$ means we first apply $D$ and then $A$.$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$

$$DA(f) = D\left(x\mapsto \int_a^x f(y)\,dy\right) = x\mapsto f(x) = f\implies DA = \id$$

$$AD(f) = A\left(x\mapsto f'(x)\right) = x\mapsto\int_a^x f'(y)\,dy  = x\mapsto f(x) - f(a) = f - f(a)$$

For the range and null-space:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$

$$f \in \Ker D \iff f' \equiv 0 \iff f = \text{const}$$

So $\Ker D = \{x \mapsto \alpha : \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, i.e. the space of constant functions.

Since $DA = \id$, for arbitrary $f \in C^k(I)$ we have $D(A(f)) = f$, so $D$ is surjective. Hence, $\Ima D = C^k(I)$.

To find $\Ima A$, notice that for every $f \in C^{k+1}(I)$ we have $$AD(\underbrace{f + f(a)}_{\in C^{k+1}(I)}) = (f + f(a)) - f(a) = f$$
so $A$ is surjective. $\Ima A = C^{k+1}(I)$ follows.

For $\Ker A$:

$$ f \in \Ker A \iff \int_a^x f(y)\,dy = 0, \forall x\in I$$

By taking the derivative of the function $x \mapsto \int_a^x f(y)\,dy \in C^{k+1}(I)$ we obtain:

$$0 = \left(x \mapsto \int_a^x f(y)\,dy\right)' = x \mapsto f(x)$$

So, $f \equiv 0$. Thus, $\Ker A = \{0\}$.